# Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast and vice versa in c

Tags: c, pointers, integer

I'm trying to write a program that gets a string, and a number, and calculates the length of it and shifting all the elents right. 
I have 2 errors:
1.assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast.
2.assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 10

int myStrlen(char*);
void shiftRight(char*, int);

int main() {
    char str[N] = {0};
    int num = 0;
    int len;
    /* input of the string */
    scanf("%s",str);
    scanf("%d",&num);
    len=myStrlen(str);


    if(num>=0) {
         shiftRight(str, num);
         printf("%s\n",str);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }


    return 0;
}

int myStrlen(char*str)
{
    int my_len=0;
    while (str[my_len] != '\0')
    {
        my_len++;
    }
    return my_len;
}



void shiftRight(char* str, int num)
{
    int i;
    char* j;
    int count;
    j=(str[N-1]);
    for(count=0;count<num;count++)
    {
        for(i=N-1;i>0;--i)
        {
            str[i]=str[i-1];
        }
        str[0]=j;
     }
}
```

Your answers are welcome,anf if you anything wrong with this code,please mention it.

Comment: And *where* do you get the errors? Please point out the locations in the code you show, with e.g. comments.

Comment: A hint though: In the `shiftRight` function, what is the type of `j`? And what is the type of `str[i]` (for any valid value of `i`)?

Comment: Thanks. Do you see anything wrong with the code?

Comment: You have a number of other issues with your code. For instance (hint), you are calculating the string length, but not using it in the shift function. You should either use a debugger to step through it, or insert printf statements to allow you to see the state of your variables while the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

As your compiler will have told you, pointer from integer without a cast is at

```
j=(str[N-1]);
```

And integer from pointer is at

```
str[0]=j;
```

You should have declared j as `char j;`

Comment: Thank you. But now when i run it, and typing lets say ball as a string and 1 to be a number, i get nothing from the program instead of getting "lbal"

Comment: @user6788452 That is a different problem, and one you should learn how to use a debugger to solve. With a debugger you can step through your code, line by line, while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: @user6788452 This article from the codeblocks wiki might help http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks

Answer (score 0):

> But now when i run it, and typing lets say ball as a string and 1 to
>   be a number, i get nothing from the program instead of getting "lbal"

You have all the correct elements but that's not enough.  Writing a program is telling a story, you need to set the scene, describe what happens along the way and conclude your narrative.  A story with elements out of order is nonsense, as is a program.

Specific issues with your code: you're saving of the last character (to restore it to the beginning of the string) is in the wrong place; you're using the allocation of the string when you should be using it's length (and conveniently, you have a function for that!); this is really more of a rotation than a shift; use the most descriptive variable names you can, not the shortest you can get away with; pick one indentation style and stick with it -- it can change between programs you write but shouldn't change within an individual program.

Below is a rework of your code addressing some of the issues above:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRING_SIZE 10

int myStrlen(char *string)
{
    int length = 0;

    while (string[length] != '\0')
    {
        length++;
    }

    return length;
}

void rotateRight(char *string, int number)
{
    int length = myStrlen(string);

    for (int count = 0; count < number; count++)
    {
        char j = string[length - 1];

        for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            string[i] = string[i - 1];
        }

        string[0] = j;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char string[STRING_SIZE] = {0};
    int number = 0;

    /* input of the string */

    scanf("%s", string);
    scanf("%d", &number);

    if (number > 0)
    {
        rotateRight(string, number);
        printf("%s\n", string);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", string);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% ./a.out
elephant
3
anteleph
%
```

Comment: Thank you very much. but i whould like to ask some things: from what I understand, the MAIN reason if not the only reason was that there was not a connection between my functions. But why I cant say that N=length? Is the allocation equals to the size of the string(totally new to programming).

Comment: @user6788452,  `N` is the size of the largest string your program can handle, `length` is the size of the string you're working on right now.  If you rotate using `N` then you potentially rotate garbage into the left end of the string.  If you rotate using `length`, you're only working with the characters of the input string.